# error Component name "Posts" should always be multi-word vue/multi-word-component-names

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Posts from './views/Posts'

//Next you need to call Vue.use(Router) to make sure that Router is added as a middleware to our Vue project.
Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    //The default mode for Vue Router is hash mode. 
    //It uses a URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won’t be reloaded when the URL changes.  
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'posts',
            component: Posts,
        },
        
    ]
})
```

I am trying above code and run server then it shows this error :

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                   3:52:40 AM
>
> [eslint]
> C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\travel-test-main\django_vue\vue2\hello\src\views\Posts.vue
> 1:1  error  Component name "Posts" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

Answer (score 2):

It's always important to understand what an error is trying to tell you.

First, the provided code snippet does not show where the error is.  The error says it's in your `src\views\Posts.vue` file. I believe you've given us code from your router file.

Second, the error also says that it comes from [eslint](https://dev.to/shivambmgupta/eslint-what-why-when-how-5f1d) which is a utility meant to enforce specific coding formatting standards. You're running into an error from an eslint rule called "vue/multi-word-component-names".  Simple google search returns the [rule documentation](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html).
Anyways, to resolve this error you can either follow the rule and give the name of your component a multi-word name, or you can change your [eslint config](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files) and simply turn the rule off.

**.eslintrc**

```js
"rules": {
  "vue/multi-word-component-names": "off"
}
```